# Fix an image at top but have auto-margin on sides

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="fix-to-top">
    <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to fix the position of the image to the top of the page -- so that it is always at the top of the page no matter how far down the user scrolls. In addition, I want the image to **always** stay in the center of the page, so if a user re-sizes his browser, the image stays in the center. Here is what I tried, but wasn't getting the result:

```
.fix-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 2000px;
}
.fix-to-top .background-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, the side margins aren't doing 'auto'. How would I correctly do this?

Comment: Hey i [updated my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12650830/1577396). maybe this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    background: orange;
    top: 50%;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jXdxr/1/

Comment: This actually doesn't fix it to the top. If you change the size of the browser window it 'floats' vertically. I need to to **always** stay at the top.

Comment: For me it sticks to the side of the browser on the right hand side in the center, regardless of scrolling, isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqnKQ/4/)

No need of using two div's

You can use **[`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-attachment)** and **[`background-postion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position)** properties to achieve it